# mail function in php

Tags: php

I have been working on php form submission. i get data from HTML form and after validating through JavaScript and ajax sent to mail.php file but code is not working.
below is code

**HTML file:**

```html
<!-- carousel document -->

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#feed").on('submit',function(e){

        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'feedburner.php',
            data:$("#feed").serialize(),
            cache: false,
            success:function(data){
                $("#spnGetStarted").hide(); 
                $("#spnGetThank").show();
                setTimeout(function(){$("#spnGetThank").hide(); },2000);
                $("#sngfld").val('');
            },
            error:function(data){
                $("#error").show().fadeOut(5000);
            }
        });

        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

This is Form

```
<form role="form" class="navbar-form navbar-leftn" name="feed" id="feed"  action="" method="post">
    <div class="float-left1">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" id="sngfld"  placeholder="Your email address" class="form-control"  name="email">
            <span style="display: none;" id="spnGetStarted" class="formerorban">Please enter valid email address.</span>
            <span style="display: none; background-color:green;" id="spnGetThank" class="formerorban">Thank you</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="float-left2">
        <input type="submit" value="Let's start Talking" id="sngbtn" class="btn btn-primary">
    </div>
</form>
```

Mail php file is below

```
<?php 
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $msg = $_POST["email"];
    $message = wordwrap($msg, 70,"\r\n");
    $from = 'TechnoCube';
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'From: ' . $from . PHP_EOL ;
    $headers .= 'Reply-To: ' .$email . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    mail("myemailaddress@example.com",$message,$headers);
```

?>

Comment: 1. `code is not working` is not clear at all. 2. try to localize the problem.

Comment: What isnt working? "NOT WORKING" is a bold statement which could cover hundreds of possibilities

Comment: Are you getting any error message?

Comment: mail functions documentation is WRONG, only use `\r\n` on windows, use only `\n` on on everything else.

Comment: what @Jasen said is factually wrong: RFC 5322, Section 2.2 states "Header fields are lines beginning with a field name, followed by a colon (":"), followed by a field body, and terminated by CRLF."

Comment: @Digifaktur the man page for sendmail(1) disagrees. and that's the important one.  php does something like `popen("sendmail -t",'w')`  and `\r` is harmful there.

Comment: Source? sendmail writes: "The format of messages shall be as defined in RFC 2822:Internet Message Format." RFC 2822 Section 2.2 uses the identical phrasing as RFC 5322

Comment: "everyone" uses /usr/sbin/sendmail with ordinary text files - today I can't provoke the problem on the command-line on systems with exim or sendmail as the MTA in the past it has given me grief.

Answer (score 1):

php mail function is not a good option for sending mail.

I absolutely recommend PHP mailer Class. its easy to use and can do anything like send attachment or use smtp server.

you can find it here http://phpmailer.worxware.com/

Comment: mail() works fine here, it you treat it right. phpmailer is ok if you only have simple requirements,

Comment: But php mailer donot support some of smtp.Like I was using php mailer with godaddy smtp server and it dint work.So I prefer swift mailer

Comment: maybe that smtp server used authentication, so you have to authenticate your connection.

Comment: @Kiyan I had set the Authentication to be true